# Innodb update locking

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock

I have been having all sorts of trouble with a particular update query, which seems like it should be very unproblematic. I've changed the names, but the table is:

```
CREATE TABLE `problem_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('TYPE1','TYPE2','TYPE3') NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `reference_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `source` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `problem_field` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `type_idx` (`type`),
  KEY `value_idx` (`value`(12)),
  KEY `latest_id` (`reference_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and the query causing problems is:

```
 UPDATE problem_table SET problem_field = 20000101 WHERE id = 6526153;
```

the values of `problem_field` and `id` here don't seems to be important.

This single update is deadlocking repeatedly with various select queries on `problem_table`, so my question is - what locks exactly are taken out by this simple update query? I should add that both of the deadlocking transactions just contain the single query.

I have read through [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking.html) but they don't seem particularly comprehensive.

For reference, here is a query it deadlocks with and its INNODB STATUS report, although this is only one example out of many different queries:

```
INSERT INTO temp
SELECT
    p.*,
    DATE(p.date)
FROM
    problem_table p
WHERE p.type IN ('TYPE1', 'TYPE2')
    AND p.source = 'FOO';


------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
161107  0:00:00
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 3C7788A94, ACTIVE 69 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 10 lock struct(s), heap size 1248, 7 row lock(s), undo log entries 6
MySQL thread id 6558222, OS thread handle 0x7f44a606d700, query id 3110073624 164.55.80.105 sym_dbuser Updating
-- user=XXX progname=XXX host=XXX pid=XXX ldsn=XXX
-- DBI::db=HASH(0x1d15ecb0)
UPDATE problem_table SET problem_field = 'XXXX-XX-XX XX:XX:XX'WHERE id = 'XXXXX'
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 1069083 page no 313 n bits 280 index `PRIMARY` of table `XXX`.`problem_table` trx id 3C7788A94 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 3C766F450, ACTIVE 831 sec fetching rows, thread declared inside InnoDB 39
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
47612 lock struct(s), heap size 5339576, 9395927 row lock(s), undo log entries 9194153
MySQL thread id 6558799, OS thread handle 0x7f4203cb6700, query id 3108758081 172.29.1.16 XXX Sending data
-- user=XXX progname=XXX host=XXX pid=XXX ldsn=sym@symprod

INSERT INTO temp
SELECT
    p.*,
    DATE(p.date)
FROM
    problem_table p
WHERE p.type IN ('TYPE1', 'TYPE2')
    AND p.source = 'FOO';
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 1069083 page no 313 n bits 280 index `PRIMARY` of table `XXX`.`problem_table` trx id 3C766F450 lock mode S
*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 1069083 page no 82008 n bits 280 index `PRIMARY` of table `XXX`.`problem_table` trx id 3C766F450 lock mode S waiting
*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
```

EDIT:

For the benefit of anyone reading this down the line, I've just found out that INNODB is capable of detecting deadlocks from 3 or more transactions, but it only lists the victim and the transaction that wanted the victim's lock in the deadlock report - the remaining transactions aren't listed in there at all.

To see this, run three transactions like:

```
T(ransaction)1 take S lock on R(ecord) 1
T2 take S lock on R2
T2 take X lock on R1 (hangs waiting for T1)
T3 take S lock on R3
T3 take X lock on R2 (hangs waiting for T2)
T1 take X lock on R3 (deadlock detected)
```

Comment: nope, it is triggerless

Comment: It looks like the INSERT INTO temp SELECT ... -query locks the problem_table. So if this INSERT INTO query happens, your update-query waits. Depending on the amount of rows (over 9 Million are locked) this could make the update-query fail because no log can be achieved in a useful time. Do you have a slow query log and can you see, how long these insert-queries take and how often they are executed?

Comment: @Seb I do have a slow query log, but these updates don't appear in it - they are only appearing as deadlocks, in which case the other transaction is always the victim

Comment: @RyanVincent there is nothing else happening in the transactions. The deadlock is reproducible running just the two queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the basic question that was buried in the middle there, the locks taken out by

```
  UPDATE problem_table SET problem_field = 20000101 WHERE id = 6526153;
```

where `problem_table` is defined as in the question are just:

- An [IX lock](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-intention-locks) on `problem_table`
- An [X lock](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-record-locks) on record `6526153`

Turns out that things weren't quite as I'd described though - tool 1 that was performing the problematic update does no transaction management, so all of its updates form their own transactions normally.

However, in this case there was a tool 2, which uses tool 1, and wraps all its actions up in its own transaction. Therefore, this single update was part of a larger transaction after all (containing an update on another row in the same table).

This makes it much clearer why a deadlock could occur - the fix being implemented is to make these two updates in order of their primary key (there's a good post on this sort of deadlocking [here](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/08/03/a-little-known-way-to-cause-a-database-deadlock/)).

I will be considering some schema changes as suggested by @fancyPants as well, although this will take a bit more work - the example I provided is pretty stripped down, and the table design overall is fairly horrendous. It could definitely use some sprucing up...

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you don't have a good index to use for your insert...select query.

You have an index on `type`, but that's (I guess) totally useless. This column can only have 3 different values. Your query even asking for 2 out of 3. An index is the better the more selective it is. In other words, the closer this

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT columnname) / COUNT(*) FROM yourtable;
```

is to 1, the better is your index.

The use of the index is too expensive here, cause it actually it requires MySQL to read the index first and then the actual data. Therefore it's cheaper to just read the entire table.

For your case an index on `source` would be better. Or even a combined index on `(source, type)`. (The order is important here, the more selective one first!)

Comment: Could you clarify how having a different index would avoid a deadlock?

Comment: It would avoid a deadlock, because your query doesn't use an index at all. Therefore InnoDB uses a row-level lock over the entire table. See the last statement [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html). And you can also see in your `show engine innodb status` output, that your query holds 9395927 row locks.

Comment: thanks for that. I still don't see why a row-level lock over the whole table should cause a deadlock though, it should just hold up the update query - would you be able to explain what that update query is doing in terms of locking that allows a deadlock to occur? That was what I was really getting at with this question

Comment: My guess is, that the select first puts a shared lock, then the insert sets the exclusive lock. But at that point your update query has already tried to set an exclusive lock. Therefore the deadlock. Almost the same scenario [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-deadlock-example.html) and more information [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locks-set.html) (see the part about the insert statement).

Comment: A very common way to decrease the frequency of deadlocks is to get out of the way fast.  With the recommended composite index, the `INSERT..SELECT` will run a lot faster.

Comment: @rbennett485 So, any more feedback?

Comment: @fancyPants, I've posted an answer above. Thanks for the help!